# Why was my comment asking for clarification on endgames removed?

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette

Update: Anton Menshov admitted to downvoting this post and while Anton Menshov has a downvote on h post, it was not from me.

> yes. I don't appreciate the tone of the original post, and I think it can be formulated way differently. In addition, I do not believe that the research on how the comments work has been done.

---

I commented this

> 'Not to mention these type of endgames are really only studied by GMs because at master level these endgames do not happen enough to justify studying them extensively' --> really? i believe i've encountered single queen vs single rook a few times but with pawns. i know i encountered king queen vs king rook pawnless at least once. [Karsten Müller](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/36829) even has a chapter on it in volume 3 of h 14 volume endgame course. it seems like a pretty basic thing of course i skipped that chapter lol

[here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/22696). It was deleted. Good thing I use [typio](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/typio-form-recovery/djkbihbnjhkjahbhjaadbepppbpoedaa?hl=en).

Why? I am asking if the claims made are indeed true given what I have observed from my own experience.

What am I supposed to do, create a chat and never make another comment? Ask a new question every time I'm not fully confident in an answer?

Comment: I deleted several of the comments on this page.  I'm generally okay with more contentious conversations on meta, but we're still going to make sure that everything is civil.

Comment: @BCLC among other suboptimal practices that are easy fixes, why is some 'Update' based on an answer given to this question itself, presented not only as part of your question but indeed **above** the question? Please think a little about how to be comprehensible easily to a reader

Answer (score 10):

As the other users have noted, you are not using comments for their intended purpose. Let me break it down for you:

> i believe i've encountered single queen vs single rook a few times but with pawns.

That is **completely irrelevant** to the question, and hence the answer.

> i know i encountered king queen vs king rook pawnless at least once.

That is related to the question, but it's still an N=1 example. I said they *don't occur that much in practice*; that does not mean they never occur.

> Karsten Müller even has a chapter on it in volume 3 of h 14 volume endgame course.

OK, fine, the quote I copied is from another one of his books. Still, it doesn't help improving the comment.

> it seems like a pretty basic thing of course i skipped that chapter

Smart move, but completely irrelevant.

> lol

Please, **stop** doing that. We're [building a library here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/tour), this is different from hanging out with friends. Use the kind of language they would use in chess books.

In general, I would advice you to stop using comments altogether. Or at least limit it to your own posts or answers to your questions. It will save both you and many community members a lot of frustration.

Let me end with a positive note: thank you for attempting to salvage a badly posed but potentially interesting question. It received many downvotes because it was perceived as essentially being a rant; I hope the author is OK with the edit.

Answer (score 8):

I strongly believe you are not using comments correctly and expect the properties that they are not designed to possess on Stack Exchange (notice, SE is different from discussion forums).

A lot of the discussions should actually happen in chat, rather than in comments.

Excerpt from [Overall Meta FAQ: How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/383809):

> ##### What are comments for, and when shouldn't I comment?
>
> ...
>
> They are **not** for:
>
> ...
>
> - Secondary back-and-forth discussion or debate; use chat instead
>
> ...

Also:

> Comments are [temporary "Post-It" notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) left on a question or answer. You should not expect them to be around forever. Once a clarification has been made, an edit added to the post to include new information, or the issue in the comment is otherwise resolved, it can be deleted.

Notice, I would also discourage editing in the whole history of comments directly into the question without integrating the essence when it is actually needed (example: [this post of yours](https://chess.stackexchange.com/revisions/37403/6)).

Answer (score 8):

Comments are useful to share additional context and to point out omissions (or ask for clarification) from questions and answers.  Some comments are useful as permanent additions, but others are really only helpful for the short period of time before an edit is made.

Generally speaking, the comments that refer to older versions of a post are removed over time, especially if the page appears in web searches frequently.

If comments are even remotely unfriendly or rude, they're subject to being removed, no matter how useful they might be.  There's really just no need to be confrontational since we're all here to try and share knowledge, not to prove that we know more than other people.  If your comment includes "no offense" that's probably an indication that it could be reworked to make it nicer.

Finally, if the same comment is deleted multiple times, then come ask about it instead of working it into the answer.  There's probably a reason that it's being removed.